How does 'io_context' poll work and how to poll in a tight loop?
I have been playing around with Boost.Asio and I want to be able to busy poll rather than simply perform an io_context.run().
My application currently consists of 2 io_context objects, each running on a separate thread of execution. All was well when I was using work guards with io_context.run(). When I switched to poll, I experience premature exit of the application. I found out what polling exactly does so, now my assumption is that it should be called in a tight loop (perhaps at the end of the tight loop).
Is this the correct approach? For reference, the reason I need to do this is that I need to achieve the lowest possible latency. Threads are running on isolated cores, with proper thread affinity setup. Now I need to make sure the whole system will busy poll.
I have tried to add work guards, which I later found out was not the correct approach. I also tried to run the polling in a very tight while loop, but this just starved the async operations that "were" supposed to run on the same thread.
Currently, I just call poll at the end of my main while loop. You can imagine the code structured as follows:
co_spawn(ioc_,runner(),detached);
runner() {
   while(true) {
     // async 
    // logic 
     // async
     ioc_.poll()
  }
}


What's wrong with ioc.run()? For lower latency, consider https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/concurrency_hint.html and avoid type-erased executors.

Wait. Is runner() somehow a coroutine? That can never work. And why would you? Look at concurrency hints and perhaps immediate executors. Regardless, without real code we can almost be sure your optimizing the wrong thing (since it cannot be measured).
